# Executable File in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, executable

I finished creating a basic mobile app on Xcode and I want to be able to generate an executable file (much like a jar executable) that has compiled all my related files and can launch my app on another computer without Xcode. I've looked at other resources online that have directed me to the picture below and I think the highlighted file is my executable (correct me if I'm wrong) but when I double click it I get an alert telling me that "this application is not supported on this type of Mac".

Any insight on how I can generate an executable or find one automatically generated by Xcode would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You realize that iOS and OS X are two different operating systems, right? You can only execute iOS apps inside a simulator in OS X.

Comment: Are you looking to ship your iOS app to the store?

Comment: You cannot distribute a mobile executable unless through the app store, or if you qualify as an Enterprise developer.